# Scaling trouble with jointjs

Tags: javascript, html, scale, jointjs

I tryed implementing a scaling tool in my jointjs paper.
The function works well but i have a problem with the rendering of my links.
All my 'strokes' are defined with a width of 2.

With a scale of 1 my paper looks like this :
[image]

And with a scale of 2 my paper looks like this :
[image]

My problem is that the links between my differents elements does not keep a stroke width of 2 but grow as the scale grows too. While the strokes on my others elements keep a width of 2.
Do any of you may know what is the solution to keep links with a wanted witdh or a workaround to achieve what i want to do ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

css property `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke` on link's element `path` might help you out